# How can I find out, if a Java type is convertible from/to JSON

Tags: java, jsonb-api

JSON-B converts types like `LocalDate` to/from a simple String. When I have a `Type`, how can I find out if JSON-B will convert this type directly, i.e. if it's a scalar type?

I don't have an instance, so I can't even just try to convert it to a String and see if it contains curly braces.

Or do I have to look for types that have a `valueOf` or `parse` method or a Constructor having exactly one String parameter?

Comment: The answer depends on which JSON library you are using, so your question cannot be answered. --- *FYI:* Most classes can be scalar types. If a string representation can be generated for the class, and that can be used to re-instantiate the object, then the class *can* be scalar as far as JSON is concerned, either by following conventions, or by registering (de)serializers with the JSON framework.

Comment: I'm not an expert in JSON but the generic approach would be a try-catch szenarion.

Comment: @tifi90 I think they want to know *a priori*, not *a posteriori*.

Comment: I use JSON-B (JSR 365), and I don't have an instance nor a JSON string available. I'm working on a meta level, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to check ahead of time if a given type can be serialized to JSON (i.e. convert from strongly typed to weakly typed format), but there isn't a way to check if a given type can be deserialized to a POJO until you have an actual JSON value at runtime (i.e. convert from weakly typed format to strongly typed format).

In general, the rules for a type being serializable are simply:

- The class must be accessible (public or protected)
- If the class is an inner class it must be static
- Zero or more public fields/getters that contain/return serializable types

In general, the rules for a type being deserializable are:

- The class must be accessible (public or protected)
- If the class is an inner class it must be static
- Zero or more public fields/setters that contain/return deserializable types
- The class must have a public no-args constructor (or a ctor annotated with `@JsonbCreator`)
- OR The class must have a public static factory method annotated with `@JsonbCreator`

You may find that what constitutes a "convertible type" is a very broad criteria in JSON-B (or any other Java JSON library). For example, the JSON string `{}` can be deserialized into any Type that has a public no-args constructor. Likewise, a Java class that has no public fields or getter methods will serialize to the JSON string `{}`.

Since a convertible type is such a broad term, it would be helpful if you specified a bit further what you are trying to achieve -- maybe there is a more specific approach I could suggest.

---

#### Additional info:

Many of the commonly used classes from the JDK are supported. See [sections 3.3 - 3.5 of the JSON-B spec](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsonb-api/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/jsonb.adoc#33-basic-java-types) for the full list. Aside from the built-in classes, requirements are specified in [section 3.7 of the JSON-B spec](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsonb-api/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/jsonb.adoc#37-java-class).

For deserialization there are more requirements than serialization. They are described in detail in section 3.7 and [section 4.5](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsonb-api/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/jsonb.adoc#45-custom-instantiation).

Comment: My question was about types that don't have any fields but are (de)serialized from/to a simple JSON String.